# removing background image of uibarbuttonitem back button

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I want to remove background of a UIViewController backbutton.

How can I do that?

I tried following code

```
backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] landscapeImagePhone:nil style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:nil];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

But it didn't work!

Comment: you are trying to modify `UINavigationBar` `back button's` back image?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that!

Comment: please clear your Question??explain with Image

Comment: and it will give warning if you use UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel in style too...

Comment: you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
[backBarButton setAction:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
-(void)backButtonPressed{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont try to modify `UINavigationBar`'s backbutton image. That's not possible because that comes by default.

Rather put another customize `UIButton` as `UINavigationBar` item and then you can customize that as per your needs.

```
UIButton *btnItem = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[btnItem setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnItem addTarget:self action:@selector(btnItem_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnItem];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to implement functionality!

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigation.backBarButtonItem` is not used to set the back button of current view controller, it is used to **set back button of controller pushed from current view controller**.

Say now `ViewController1` is showing in `UINavigationController`, you set `backBarButton` of `ViewController1`. The back button won't change, but then you push `ViewController2`, you'll see the back button of `ViewController2` is what you set for `ViewController1`.

To set back button of `ViewController1`, either you set it in the ViewController pushing `ViewController1`, or you user `self.navigationItem.leftBarbuttonItem = YourButton`, the latter way you need to add event listener on YourButton

Comment: Thanks, But what should I exactly do to return to first viewController?

Comment: If you are setting backBarbuttonItem, you need do nothing. If you are setting leftBarButtonItem, you need to set the target and selector of the UIBarButtonItem you assigned to UINavigationController.leftBarButtonItem, in the selector, call UINavitaionController popViewController manually.